# Show a message if a text is copied successfully(alternative to alert)

Tags: javascript, html

```
function Hello() {
    var text_to_copy = document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text_to_copy).then(
        function(){
            alert("Copied successfully"); // success 
        })
      .catch(
         function() {
            alert("Error"); // error
      });
}
```

I want the code to flash the "Copied duccessfully" or "Error" instead of showing in alert box

Comment: Alternative to an alert can be anything. What have you tried?

Comment: A small message that pops up and disappears after a while is sometimes called a toast or a toast notification.  Perhaps that will help you finding a component or tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A snackbar/toast message would work perfectly. But you will need to code your own implementation for it ofc.

**An example of how to implement this:**

*HTML:*

```
<span id="snackbar">Successfully Copied</span>
```

*CSS:*

```
#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

/* This will be activated when the snackbar's class is 'show' which will be added through JS */
#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

/* Animations for fading in and out */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

*Javascript:*

```
function showSnackBar() {
  var sb = document.getElementById("snackbar");

  //this is where the class name will be added & removed to activate the css
  sb.className = "show";

  setTimeout(()=>{ sb.className = sb.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
```

You can edit & style to your liking. (ofc ideally you should edit this to pass whatever string message you want the Snackbar/toast to display, something i left out for you to enjoy)